# how to combine the two sql queries into one?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Hello peoples

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user` = '$user'";
$res1=mysql_query($sql1);
if(!$res1||mysql_num_rows($res1)<1){
$sql2="INSERT INTO `table` (`user`) VALUES ('$user')";
$res2=mysql_query($sql2);
if(!$res2){echo 'Yes';}else{echo 'No';}
}
else{echo 'user already exists!';}
```

Can to combine the two queries into one?

Comment: Where does `$user` come from?

Comment: Set the column `user` as **`UNIQUE`**

Comment: The DOCTOR from TARDIS if i set UNIQUE column, value give automatic or no ? me need set value from 100000 to 9999999

Comment: if i have dublicte value me need automatic set new value $user, if i will be use ignore, my row not insert only...

Comment: http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql-affected-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your column `user` to **UNIQUE**, there'll be a maximum of *ONE* entry of each user. To `ALTER TABLE` and make the column `UNIQUE`:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX `user` (`user`);
```

And then, a single query like this would be good:

```
$res = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `table`(`user`) VALUES( '".mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "')";
echo ( mysql_affected_rows() == 0 ) ? "No" : "Yes";
```

[mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

Comment: if i have dublicte value me need automatic set new value $user, if i will be use ignore, row not insert only... if i have dublicate, me need auto generate new value $user.

Comment: then insert table user ,without giving any value to the auto increment field sql will do it for you..or else you post your table structure @john

Comment: problem!
 i give 'Yes' every time.  Whow i can see that `user` with this value already exists in `table` ?

Comment: @JohnSmith Edited the reply. Included [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 3):

Use this query .

```
INSERT INTO USER SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE user='$user'
```

the number of column in `table` table and user table must be same ,their type also.

you can also use

```
INSERT into user
SELECT * from table 
WHERE user='$user'
AND 
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USER 
              WHERE USER = '$user')
```

Comment: INSERT INTO TABLE USER ? What its ?

Comment: sorry just my mistake. i have edited.